# Relation between implication and subset relation

Tags: logic

If $a \implies b$ can we then generally say that $a \subseteq b$ ? 
For example: 
if $a: x > 15$ and $b: x >10$ then clearly $a \implies b$ and if we look at the sets represented by **a** $\lbrace16,17,18..\rbrace$ and **b** $\lbrace 11,12,13... \rbrace$ it is also obvious that $a \subset b$.

Comment: The connective $\to$ is used between sentences and not always a sentence express a condition regarding a set. What is linked is the formula $\forall x (A(x) \to B(x))$ with the inclusion $A \subseteq B$ where $A = \{ x \mid A(x) \}$ and the same for $B$.

Comment: The reason is that in set theory $\subseteq$ is defined in terms of $\to$ (and the universal quantifier) : $A \subseteq B \Leftrightarrow \forall x (x \in A \to x \in B)$.

Comment: You cannot use $a\Rightarrow b$ and $a\subseteq b$ with the same $a, b$. This doesn't make sense. For $a\Rightarrow b$ to work both $a, b$ have to be sentences. On the other hand for $a\subseteq b$ to work both $a, b$ have to be sets. Even in your example you clearly distinguish between sentences $a, b$ and underlying set conditions $x > 15$, $x>10$. You even say yourself "sets represented". Now if you can define how this "representation" works in general case then we can help. So if you have a way to generate a set from a sentence then perhaps yes. Who knows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No but you can say:

Let $P$ be $(x ∈ A)$ 
Let $Q$ be $(x ∈ B)$

$A ⊆ B ≡ ∀x, P → Q $

$⊆$ is for sets
$→$ is for propositions

Note: You cannot say the same for $A ⊂ B$ 
Why?

Let $A$ be ${1}$ 
Let $B$ be ${1}$ 
Let $P$ be $(x ∈ A)$ 
Let $Q$ be $(x ∈ B)$

$A ⊂ B$ is false.
$∀x, P → Q$ is true.
Therefore $A ⊂ B$ cannot be equivalent to $∀x, P → Q$